# WPF DataGrid: How to clear selection programmatically?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selection

How would one just clear it?

There is `UnselectAll` or `UnselectAllCells` methods, but they don't work. Also, setting `SelectedItem = null` or `SelectedIndex = -1` does not work either.

Also I do not want to completely disable the selection, I just want to clear the current selection (if any) and set a new selection programmatically.

Answer (score 26):

```
dataGrid.UnselectAll()
```

For rows mode

Answer (score 5):

To clear current selection, you can use this code (as you see it is different whether the mode is Single or Extended)

```
if(this.dataGrid1.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
    this.dataGrid1.SelectedCells.Clear();

if (this.dataGrid1.SelectionMode != DataGridSelectionMode.Single) //if the Extended mode
    this.dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Clear();
else 
    this.dataGrid1.SelectedItem = null;
```

To select new items programmatically, use this code:

```
if (this.dataGrid1.SelectionMode != DataGridSelectionMode.Single) 
{    //for example, select first and third items
    var firstItem = this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().FirstOrDefault();
    var thirdItem = this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();

    if(firstItem != null)
        this.dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Add(firstItem);
    if (thirdItem != null)
        this.dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Add(thirdItem);
}
else
    this.dataGrid1.SelectedItem = this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().FirstOrDefault(); //the first item
```

Comment: @miliu Yes, my previous code wasn't correct. I fixed my answer.

Comment: @vortex: I don't know if I did something wrong, but this new code for clearing the selection doesn't work for me either. I'm using this code in MouseDoubleClick event.

Comment: For my case, I found a workaround: The selection disappears when I refresh the datacontext by calling "Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => grid.Items.Refresh()));"

Comment: Just a note...WPF DataGrid is great, but a few minor things drive me crazy.

Comment: @miliu Dispatcher is used if it is necessary to use a wpf element from a thread which isn't UI thread. But threads in the event handler look strange. Anyway I haven't seen your complete code, so the Dispatcher class might be necessary.

Comment: at the Silverlight Datagrid, if you don't use Extended Selection mode (multi-selection) it seems you can't do grid.SelectedItems.Clear() but have to do grid.SelectedItem=null instead. Maybe something similar is true in the WPF one?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis My answer was long ago and I don't remember. But my code has if-else combination which uses either `SelectedItems.Clear` or `SelectedItem = null` depending on the selection mode. If new SelectionMode values appear, I think this if-else should be rewritten.

Comment: yeah, seems they use the same strange pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
DataGrid.UnselectAllCells()
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling and reenabling the DataGrid worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually looking to clear *selected* rows/cells?
My understanding was that you wanted to clear the entire `DataGrid`.
If so, you could do this:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
```